# Bash script on a Linux machine and it needs to connect from it over SSH to another Bluecoat device and run the script over there

Tags: shell-script

The idea is to connect to a remote device bluecoat proxy over SSH, let the script do the authentication and execute the commands over in another script, create file with name date & time and save the output to local directory from where the script is running, without the need of upload this script to a remote server.

I have prepared the script as below: `HC.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME=$1
Date=`date +"%b-%d-%y_%I-%M"`
ssh user@$1 'bash -s' < Proxy.sh >HC_$1_$Date.txt
```

I have another script with set of commands : `Proxy.sh`

```
#!bin/bash
echo "Please print me to test1"
HOSTNAME=$1

echo "  "
echo "********************************** Date***************************************"
show version
echo "  "
echo "********************************** Status***************************************"
show date
quit
```

Both the file have permission set as : `-rwxrwxrwx`

Executing sh Proxy.sh 192.x.x.x    (192.x.x.x device IP) from "Bash on Ubunto on Windows 10" I could prompt for the device, post supplying password, it just not providing anything, immediately go to next line and a file name with 0KB size creating. Basically the Proxy.sh is not running.

Comment: how to make that works ? I have the same requirement for checkpoint firewall. I am trying to see if this similar set up can be possible for checkpoint firewall as well. I have this script basically to run health check of the device.

Comment: For general health checks I would use SNMP instead

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the command as presented (`ssh remote 'bash -s' < file`) will do the redirection locally; the `<` is outside the `'` quotes so is part of the command line shell.

Comment: @Nic what happens if you do `echo echo hello | ssh user@remotehost` ?

Comment: Hi Stephen, Apologies for the late response. I modified as you said and still an empty file created.